# Concatenating a series of rotation quaternions resulting from local angular velocities

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, quaternions

I have a time series of rotation quaternions $q_t$ generated from an IMU's angular velocity readings. These rotations are in the local coordinate frame. I would like to produce a series of absolute orientation quaternions $Q_t$ resulting from concatenating the $q_t$ values together.

Given $Q_0 = 1$, an obvious choice for the absolute orientation would be $Q_t = q_t Q_{t-1}$. However, this is applying the local rotation represented by $q_t$ in the coordinate system of the current global orientation $Q_{t-1}$, which seems incorrect.

On the other hand, using $Q_t = Q_{t-1} q_t$ seems to apply the local rotations in "reverse chronological order", assuming successive left multiplication represents a successive series of rotations. This also seems incorrect.

I'm trying to figure out if the right answer is something like $Q_t = Q_{t-1} q_t Q_{t-1}^{-1}$, which (I think) rotates back from the current global orientation to the local coordinate system, then applies $q_t$, then rotates back to the global coordinate system. But this doesn't seem to produce a reasonable series of quaternion multiplications when expanded.

Any idea how to concatenate these values?

Comment: The way I know to rotate vectors using quaternions is this: take a unit quaternion $q$ which represents a rotation, and a real vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, the vector to rotate. Treat $v$ as a purely imaginary quaternion $iv_x + jv_y + k v_z$, then the rotated vector is $q v q^{-1}$. Now let's say we want to apply another rotation represented by a unit quaternion $r$, then we get $r q v q^{-1} r^{-1} = (rq) v (rq)^{-1}$, and so the quaternion which represents the rotation $q$ followed by the rotation $r$ is $rq$.

Comment: Keep in mind that everything I just said is purely by convention. If I rotated vectors by doing $q^{-1} v q$, then the composition of rotations would be $qr$: just follow the logic through. I think the only tricky thing to keep in mind is that _applying_ rotations is a conjugation, but _composing_ rotations is just multiplying quaternions (so that conjugation happens in the correct order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given $Q_0 = 1$, an obvious choice for the absolute orientation would be $Q_t = q_t Q_{t-1}$. However, this is applying the local rotation represented by $q_t$ in the coordinate system of the current global orientation $Q_{t-1}$, which seems incorrect.

I think that the paragraph above is where you go wrong. The thing you want is in fact exactly $Q_t = q_t q_{t-1} \cdots q_1$.

I also want to caution you that accumulating these things is likely to give more-and-more-wrong global transformations, diverging from the truth fairly fast. You probably already know this, but just in case, I thought I'd mention it. There's a reason that the device returns local increments rather than a global rotation. :)

Comment: Well I know that integrating over time quickly leads to drift, due to cumulative integration errors (and this is even more true with double integration, e.g. when integrating linear acceleration to calculate velocity, then integrating velocity to calculate position). (Or are there additional reasons why the global orientation will drift as local transforms are concatenated?) Yes, I am using smoothed linear acceleration to estimate the gravity vector, which gives some ability to correct for drift in at least one degree of freedom at a time.

Comment: So I guess my question is: if $Q = q_2 q_1$, is it true that both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are considered rotations in the local (IMU) coordinate system, even though their product $Q$ becomes a rotation in a global coordinate system?

Comment: Suppose that at time 0 the IMU and global coordinate system (with basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$) are aligned. Then after the first rotation, $q_1$, the IMU's first axis points in direction $f_1 = q_1 e_1 q_1^{-1}$; the second axis points in direction $f_2 = q_1 e_2 q_1^{-1}$, etc. After the second rotation, the ith axis of your coordinate system points in direction $g_i = q_2 f_i q_2^{-1}$, which, expanding, is $g_i = q_2 q_1 e_1 q_1^{-1} q_2^{-1}$, so $q_2 q_1$ is the quaternion taking you from global coords (the $e_i$s) to the second position; you can probably induct from here.

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you!